# Session variable won't echo if cleared on same page?

Tags: php

I am having a strange issue of a session variable being empty when I clear it on the same page that I attempt to echo it. Here is a quick type-up of what I am trying to do.

Take this example;

**Page A:**

```
$_SESSION['referer'] = 'abc123';
header('Location: http://www.test.com/pageb.php');
exit();
```

**Page B:**

```
function get_referer() {

    $referer = '';
    if (isset($_SESSION['referer'])) {
        $referer = $_SESSION['referer'];
        $_SESSION['referer'] = null;
        unset($_SESSION['referer']);
    }
    echo $referer;
}
```

Now when I do this on page B with the functions...

If I run it all by itself it works:

```
   get_referer();
```

When I run the echo inside the value attribute of the input (making sure to only run the function once on the page due to it being erased after being called), it didn't echo anything when I view source the page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php get_referer(); ?>" />
```

However, funny enough, if I make the input type="text" it works fine.

```
<input type="text" name="referer" value="<?php get_referer(); ?>" />
```

The issue only occurs on the value attribute for input type="hidden"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Please, give us the full source code. I assume you remember `session_start()` on both pages?

Comment: Nice job pinpointing and demonstrating the problem (I can't help, though).

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen, I tried my example and noticed it did work under the original context. I updated the question to further probe my problem.

Comment: @Fase Have you checked in the HTML output that the referer isn't there? You're not showing whether you still run `get_referer()` before or after `clear_referer()`. In fact, your example hasn't change much. I'm still not able to reproduce. You need to supply more code.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen I put in some original code where I simply unset the session variable after echoing it. In the latest update above I am not using clear_referer(), it doesn't exist in this context.;

Comment: @Fase I'm guessing you're verifying that it hasn't been set, but opening the page and choosing `View Source` in your browser. Some browsers (like Chrome) refresh the page when you attempt to view the source, in which case `get_referer()` will return ''.  Try to output `get_referer()` as plaintext.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen I am using Google Chrome... I can see that it is refreshing the page when I view source! Boy is this frustrating. You can word it into an answer and I'll mark it the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting the content with

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php get_referer(); ?>" />
```

you're not viewing it on the same page as you would have if you were using `type="text"`. When using `type="hidden"`, you're most likely right-clicking the window and choosing *View Source* in your browser. The problem is that same browsers (like Chrome) refresh the page when you do so. This means, that once you load the page, the `value` attribute actually contains `abc123`, but when you attempt to see it, the page is refreshed, and therefore the session no longer exists, hence `value` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling the `get_referer()` twice?

In the first it will echo the referer and unset. When you call in the input, the referer don't exists anymore in the session, so prints nothing.